# how to return the server side onclick from javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I would like to have onclick event on button. It will run the javascript function to return back to server side button handler if the dropdown selected value greater than 0. If the dropdown selected value less or equal to 0, then don't return the server side. My code below is always return back to server side even the dropdown selected value is 0

There is the code on aspx.vb

```
btn.Attributes("onclick") = "return getResult();"
```

Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click

```
       'do something
End Sub
```

There is javascript:

```
function getResult(){
var rtn = true;
            var ID = $('#drop').val();
            if (parseInt(ID) <=0) {
                alert('Please select product.');
                rtn = false;                   
                }
    return rtn;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think your input's value is not correctly taken in the javascript.

Once please check the value of 'ID' by printing it in console by using,

```
console.log(ID)
```

If it is not correctly taken then your condition would always fail and the value of the rtn variable would always remain true.

You can also use the **$event** of the input when listening the click() event.